# Trying to remove test data with maven and junit within Spring project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, junit

I am working on a spring project and I am writing in my junit test cases to delete some of my test data but I am getting the following error..

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
```

my junit test looks like the following:

```
public class TestRemoveTestData implements BeanFactoryAware {

    static boolean functionReturn;

    String user = "xxxx@aol.com.dev";

    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;

    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Test
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void RemoveEnrollmentRecord()
    {
        Session mySession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        //
        // Get profile record based on email address
        //
        Profile myProfile = (Profile) mySession.createCriteria(Profile.class)
                .add(Restrictions.like("email", user)).uniqueResult();
        //
        // Start to create a new Enrollment Record with a status of "U"
        //
        Enrollment newEnrollment = new Enrollment();
        newEnrollment.setProfile_id(myProfile.getProfile_id());
        newEnrollment.setContact_id(myProfile.getContact_id());
        mySession.delete(newEnrollment);
        mySession.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your spring config.  Also add which context files you are loading in your test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load your configuration files. for example, in my spring project with JPA & spring security, my config files are applicationContext.xml, applicationContext-security.xml, applicationContext-jpa.xml. You could load them as following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml"})
public class TestRemoveTestData implements BeanFactoryAware {
 ...

}
```

Note: I use the wildcard '*' to load all my config files. But you can list them in the locations={"file1","file2",...}